# Want to remove a release from Production and only keep the open testing release on store

Tags: google-developers-console, app-store-optimization

I have two releases on Console right now. I want to remove the production release and only keep the Open Testing release on store so the game is available on beta testing/ Early Access but I don't know how to remove it from the console. I cannot see the Manage Rollout option for the releases on store either.

I searched and found that Manabge release will allow me to change the rollout percentage of the release but i cannot see the option for it.